# Anotação ou método para ignorar field (xStream 1.3.1)

Tags: java, xml

Estou com um problema de CircularReferenceException quando tento fazer isso:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new JettisonMappedXmlDriver());
xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
xstream.alias("resultList", ResultList.class);
xstream.alias("resultRow", ResultRow.class);
xstream.alias("resultCol", ResultCol.class);

return xstream.toXML(lista);
```

Já estou ciente de onde o problema está, tenho a classe resultRow que tem resultCol, dentro da resultCol tem uma resultRow, ficou complicado porem é isso. E no momento não posso mudar esse esquema, preciso de algo que faça o stream.toXml ignorar o atributo resultRow dentro da resultCol para impedir o CircularReferenceException, se estiver faltando informação em minha pergunta podem requisitar.

Código que monta o ResultList :

```
protected ResultList listar(TelaSistemaConsultaUsuarioPreferencia pref, Target targetXml,
        br.com.gwsistemas.eutil.consulta.Consulta consulta) throws SQLException {
    ResultList retorno = new ResultList();
    ResultRow row = null;
    ResultCol rcol = null;
    try {
        StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder();
        sql.append("SELECT * FROM ").append(targetXml.getName());
        sql.append(" ").append(pref.getCondicaoConsulta());
        if (!pref.getOrdenacao().equals("")) {
            sql.append(" ORDER BY ").append(pref.getOrdenacao());
        }
        sql.append(" OFFSET ")
                .append(Apoio.parseInt(consulta.getPaginacao().getPaginaAtual() - 1) * pref.getLimiteResultados());
        sql.append(" LIMIT ").append(pref.getLimiteResultados());

        StringBuilder sqlQtdResultados = new StringBuilder();
        sqlQtdResultados.append("SELECT count(*) as resultados FROM ").append(targetXml.getName());
        sqlQtdResultados.append(" ").append(pref.getCondicaoConsulta());

        prepSt = con.prepareStatement(sql.toString());
        rs = prepSt.executeQuery();
        while (rs.next()) {
            row = new ResultRow();
            for (int i = 1; i <= rs.getMetaData().getColumnCount(); i++) {
                rcol = new ResultCol(row, rs.getObject(rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i)),
                        rs.getMetaData().getColumnName(i), rs.getMetaData().getColumnTypeName(i),
                        rs.getMetaData().getColumnType(i));

                if (targetXml != null) {
                    for (Column col : targetXml.getColumn()) {
                        if (col.getName().equals(rcol.getNome())) {
                            rcol.setFormat(col.getFormat());
                            rcol.setLabel(col.getLabel());
                            row.addColumn(rcol);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    row.addColumn(rcol);
                }
            }
            retorno.getRows().add(row);
        }

        if (consulta != null) {
            prepSt = con.prepareStatement(sqlQtdResultados.toString());
            rs = prepSt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                consulta.getPaginacao().setQtdResultados(rs.getInt("resultados"));
                consulta.getPaginacao().setPaginas((int) Math
                        .ceil(new Double(consulta.getPaginacao().getQtdResultados() / pref.getLimiteResultados())));
            }
        }

        return retorno;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        if (prepSt != null) {
            LOG.error("SQL_ERROR:" + prepSt);
        }
        LOG.error(e, e);
        throw e;
    } finally {
        fecharConexao();
    }
}
```

---

StackTrace :

> Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Problems calling function
>   'cg:resultListToJson'     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstFunction.getValue(AstFunction.java:211)   at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:944)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.gwTrans.consultas.consulta_002dmercadoria_002ddeposito_jsp._jspService(consulta_002dmercadoria_002ddeposito_jsp.java:595)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
>     ... 41 more Caused by:
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller$CircularReferenceException:
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:83)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:157)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:148)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:118)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:129)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:100)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:157)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:148)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:118)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:129)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:100)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:157)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:148)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:118)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:129)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:100)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:157)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:148)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:118)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:129)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:100)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:157)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:148)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:118)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:129)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:100)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:157)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:148)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:118)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:129)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:100)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:157)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:148)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:118)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:129)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:100)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:63)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:64)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:55)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:157)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:148)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:118)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:129)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:100)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:63)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.AbstractCollectionConverter.writeItem(AbstractCollectionConverter.java:64)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.collections.CollectionConverter.marshal(CollectionConverter.java:55)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshallField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:157)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.writeField(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:148)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter$2.visit(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:118)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.PureJavaReflectionProvider.visitSerializableFields(PureJavaReflectionProvider.java:129)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.doMarshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:100)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.reflection.AbstractReflectionConverter.marshal(AbstractReflectionConverter.java:58)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convert(TreeMarshaller.java:86)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:78)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.convertAnother(TreeMarshaller.java:63)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.TreeMarshaller.start(TreeMarshaller.java:98)
>     at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.marshal(AbstractTreeMarshallingStrategy.java:38)
>     at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:837)   at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.marshal(XStream.java:826)    at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:801)  at
>   com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:789)  at
>   nucleo.Apoio.resultListToJson(Apoio.java:3762)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)     at
>   org.apache.el.parser.AstFunction.getValue(AstFunction.java:199)

Comment: Tente dentro de sua classe `ResultRow` no atributo `ResultCol` e também na sua classe `ResultCol` no atributo `ResultRow` a seguinte anotação: `@XStreamOmitField`

Comment: `@XStreamOmitField
private ResultRow row;` continua o erro, fiz nas duas

Comment: Tente colocar na classe `ResultRow` a anotação `@XStreamAlias("ResultRow") `, na classe `ResultCol` a anotação `@XStreamAlias("ResultCol") ` e na classe `ResultList` a anotação `@XStreamAlias("ResultList") ` e agora sim nos atributos onde ocorre a referencia circular a anotação `@XStreamOmitField`

Comment: Se não der certo, coloquei uma possivel solução abaixo

Comment: Não funcionou, será que devo adicionar algo no lugar disso : 'xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);'

Comment: Você pode postar seu código?

Comment: Em minha primeira pergunta tem o código:
 [https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/210304/erro-de-circularreferenceexception/210313#210313]

Comment: valeu, agora so precisava do codigo que você monta o obj `lista`

Comment: Onde posso postar o código ? aqui nos comentários ou editar a pergunta?

Comment: Pode editar a pergunta

Comment: Acabei de verificar que ao remover o resultRow de dentro do resultCol e seu get, mesmo assim o erro continua, logo acho que não é ali o CircularReferenceException.

Comment: Você pode postar também o `stacktrace` ? so o ultimo bloco

Comment: Sim, irei por agora.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59943/discussion-between-brow-joe-and-mateus-veloso).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda! resolveu sim, de agora em diante vou organizar no javascript. até a próxima!

Answer (score 1):

Veja se resolve:

```
XStream xstream = new XStream(new DomDriver()) {
    protected MapperWrapper wrapMapper(MapperWrapper next) {
        return new MapperWrapper(next) {
            public boolean shouldSerializeMember(Class definedIn, String fieldName) {
                try {
                    return definedIn != Object.class || realClass(fieldName) != null;
                } catch (CannotResolveClassException cnrce) {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        };
    }
};

xstream.setMode(XStream.NO_REFERENCES);
xstream.alias("resultList", ResultList.class);
xstream.alias("resultRow", ResultRow.class);
xstream.alias("resultCol", ResultCol.class);

return XML.toJSONObject(xstream.toXML(lista));
```

Não esqueça de colocar a anotação `@XStreamOmitField` onde ocorre a referencia circular e nas classes que vão virar `XML` a anotação `@XStreamAlias('nomeDoObj')`

Comment: Não obtive sucesso tentando dessa forma.